# hide all ListObject rows but the selected one

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I'm looking for some VBA code that will hide all rows in a table except for the selected row. So in the picture below, MSFT is selected, and I'd like all of the other ListRows to go hide themselves.

How would you do that?

[image: Smaple]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a list for your table, the following should work:

```
Sub HideAllListRowsExceptTheActiveOne()
    ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Hidden = True
    ActiveCell.Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

You could run this sub using a custom button, context menu item etc.